# how to make fixed navigation bar in website

Tags: html, css

I have logo picture in top of  Web page.
After logo-> navigation bar.
after scroll down logo, how to make fixed navigation bar only. sorry for my English.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with your code and explain what you have tried and why it did not work for you.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], also see [ask].

Answer (score 2):

I cant really see what your problem is maybe you cold post a screenshot or something... But just try `postion: fixed;` in css maybe this will help!

Answer (score 1):

In order to make an element fixed use position fixed as follow:

```
.nav{
position: fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
width:100%;
}
```

if you have overlay problems use z-index property

Answer (score 0):

use `nav{position: fixed;}` in the head. Do post your code if you have further issues.